# How do I triangulate a quad along the alternate diagonal direction?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Quite often I come across a mesh where I have a quad I want to triangulate, however upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, it triangulates in the opposite direction I want it to. I'm only dealing with a single quad within the entire mesh, so I don't want to use the triangulate modifier here.

Is there an way to have more control when triangulating a single quad within a mesh?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T, answer below could be updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can choose *Fixed* or *Fixed alternate* in the redo panel after triangulating:

[image]

If you prefer an all keyboard shortcut method, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> after triangulating to rotate the edge.

---

However if you are only triangulating a single quad, you can also select the verts you want to create the edge between and press <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another option that is available is rotate edge. This is available in Mesh->Edges->Rotate Edge or the edges popup menu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

This will rotate any edge so that each end gets moved to the next vertex. You only need to select one edge but if you have two triangles selected it will rotate the edge in the middle.